# Convert a set of characters(with constants) to hex in Inno Setup (for registry)

Tags: registry, inno-setup, pascal

I need to convert the a set of characters to hex for registry while installing. I want to create the following registry binary value: `{%USERPROFILE}\Downloads\Programs` in `HKCU\Software\DownloadManager\FoldersTree\Programs` **with the constants expanded** & value name of pathW. Is it even possible to do this? If it isn't possible in inno, is it possible using any 3rd party exe or autoit script or any bat/cmd file? Please help me.

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`RegWriteBinaryValue`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_regwritebinaryvalue) function to write a binary value to registry. This function takes an ANSI string as parameter for passing data, so you can use it as long as the path that you are going to store does not contain Unicode chars.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Exactly what I wanted :)